# How do I calculate ratings for a DC switch working under AC inductive loads?

Tags: power, ac, dc, maximum-ratings

I have a 1/3 HP grinder that operates at 120V mains. The switch is broken and the only replacement I can find is an automotive DC switch rated at 12V/20A and 24A/20A. Apparently, the amperage rating is inversely proportional to the supplied voltage.

If I derate the switch for 120V as if it were DC, the switch would be 120V/2A.  This may be wrong since AC is astable.  My intuition tells me that I should calculate the RMS and use that it calculate the voltage rating, but I am not sure.  How would I go about determining the safe rating for the switch if operating under mains voltage? Do inductive loads factor in?

Comment: **IF** the manufacturer has not rated the switch for AC there is no technically safe rating **BUT** if you want the grinder to work and can tolerate burning down your house or the grinder stating when it wants or not stopping sometimes if you get it wrong **THEN** the switch you cite has some chance of working OK. Issues includes isolation and breakdown voltages, heating from current flow and Murphy.

Comment: Since Murphy rules,  Schrodinger's cat will always die.

Answer (score 0):

No, ratings like max permissible voltage and max permittable current are not interchangeable. They are what they are and must be respcted. No horse-trading.

> Do inductive loads factor in?

They usually do and they always make the current rating smaller because, with an inductive load, the stored energy can causing arcing and early contact burn out when switch goes open.

Comment: In general, AC requires higher or lower amp ratings?  All things being equal.

Comment: It's usually the same but cannot be guaranteed generally. Please, just get the right switch rating.

Comment: I'll return the switch, but for my own information. I just wanted to know. I read somewhere that when you go up in voltage, you can decrease the wire gauge,  That't why I thought it may work.

Comment: For the same power load that is true because power equals volts multiplied by amps. A switch that isn't rated for the operating voltage may produce a continuous arc when going open circuit, overheat in a matter of seconds and set any surrounding combustible matter alight.

Comment: I wonder why manufacturers would bother to serve both Low DC and high AC with separate products. Why not just create just create a one switch to cover both ratings?  The extra cost in materials for the higher rated switch is negligible and possible cheaper when economies of scale is considered.

Comment: It's all down to cost and approvals for switches used directly on power AC circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Three safe ways are to: **1.** Get the switch's data sheet and examine it to determine whether the switch can switch the AC mains and whether it can handle the grinder current. **2.**  Replace the grinder's switch with a switch rated for the grinder load. **3.** Use your DC switch and a 12 volt DC supply to operate a relay with a 12 volt coil and contacts rated to handle the grinder's voltage and current requirements.